# Do passing Django Queryset to method triggers database

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm using Django for my backend and I'm wondering whether doing following thing hits the database.

I know Django Querysets are lazy thus doing this only hits the database once :

```py
records = RecordModel.objects.all()
records = records.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3])
records = records.filter(name__in=["some", "random", "strings"])
print(records)
```

In that case the database is really triggered when we try to `print` records.

But when passing Queryset as method parameter. Is the database hit 2 times ?

For instance:

```py
def some_api_endpoint(request):
    records = RecordModel.objects.all()
    records = RecordModel.filter_queryset(records, request.query_params)
    return Response(MySerializer(records, many=True).data)
```

where `filter_queryset` performs some filtering on the queryset according to the request parameters, like this :

```py
@staticmethod
def filter_queryset(queryset, query_params):
    name = query_params.get("name")
    if name:
        queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=name)
    # Other potential filters here...
    return queryset
```

I'm wondering here if `records` are evaluated when passing it to `filter_queryset` AND when returning them in the `Response` ?

Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: the answer is typically NO but `filter_queryset` could do anything, you can see for yourself by using django-debug-toolbar or by using `django.db.connection.queries`

Comment: @JimmyPells `filter_queryset` only performs `.filter(...)` on the initial queryset and returns it filtered at the end. So it only takes filters from `request.query_params` and apply them on `records`. Ok thanks I'll look into it :).

Comment: @JimmyPells I added an example of `filter_queryset`.

Comment: so then all it's doing is chaining multiple `.filter` calls to the queryset which you stated in the first example of your question that querysets are lazy and only hit the database one time

Comment: @JimmyPells Okay perfect thank you for the confirmation. I hesitated because I thought it would evaluate the queryset to be able to pass it to the method. Thanks ! But If I want to filter according to a non-DB attribute (like a python `@property` on my model), I'll have to iterate on the queryset and this, however, will hit the DB I guess ?!

Comment: you are correct